Screen blurriness: driver color misalignment?
My new OLED screen (Philips Evnia 42M2N8900) causes a lot of eye strain when working with text and it appears to be related to blurriness. In particular, the following examplary close up photos seem to suggest colours are not properly aligned horizontally, showing red/green artifacts on left/right sides of colour changes:




I am quite sure this is a driver or firmware issue, not a hardware issue (hence asking it here instead of on the Hardware Recommendations Q&A), because the built in screen menu does not seem to show this color misalignment:

I have done some search online and tried the following so far:

downloading Philips SmartControl Software and updating tthe monitor's drivers (suggested by Philips support)
reinstalling the latest display and graphics card drivers on Windows 11
tweaking and enabling/disabling Windows ClearType
tweaking settings in the screen's menu (e.g. color profiles and enabling/disabling pixel burn-in measures)
tweaking windows display settings (e.g. setting scaling to 100%, activating HDR), switching to internal graphics
tweaking 3D settings in the NVIDIA Control Panel.
performing Windows HDR Calibration
Try the mintor on different Windows 10/11 PCs

However, none of this has solved the problem. Any help on fixing it would be greatly appreciated.
System: ROG Flow X13 (laptop)

Windows 11 Home
AMD Ryzen™ 9 7940HS
NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 4070 Laptop GPU 8GB GDDR6 + ROG Boost

N.B. I do know that OLED/high res screens are more likely to cause eye strain in general, but I've personally never had problems with them before and have worked with many different screens in the past.

Have you adjusted Windows ClearType, designed specifically for that issue? https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80598-turn-off-cleartype-windows-10-a.html. In fact, misadjusted, ClearTRype can cause the issue.

@DrMoishe Pippik Thanks for pointing it out. I haven't tried tweaking ClearType, however, now that I have, unfortunately it did not solve the issue. I will edit my question to list what I tried.

Try changing the output color format (RGB 444 is generally preferred for text on most displays). You can find the option in the NVIDIA Control Panel under Change resolution or in the Intel Graphics Command Center.
You may need to reduce the refresh rate (and apply the change) to expose other output color formats and bit depths.

A bug in some earlier NVIDIA drivers may mean you need to set the output settings more than once before the change is applied.
